# How to visually affect all items in an android listview row upon click?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio-2.2

I have a listview adapter which uses a linear layout for its rows , each row simply contains two text boxes.

[image]

I need to highlight the **whole row** when either the code or the book name is touched.

The layout XML for each row of the listadapter ( removed unnecessary properties for brevity)

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    android:id="@+id/bookrowbackground">
    <TextView
        ...
        android:id="@+id/book_code"          
        android:onClick="ToggleBookSelection" />

    <TextView
        ...
        android:id="@+id/book_name"
        android:onClick="ToggleBookSelection"           
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

The **ToggleBookSelection** handler

```
public void ToggleBookSelection(View view) {
        TextView selectedTextView = (TextView)view;
       //Some code lines not related to the question ...
            selectedTextView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
            selectedTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
```

But this only highlights ONE box at a time, like below

[image]

I have googled and using the same tag for each row textbox seems to be one solution but I'm not sure if that is the cleanest way to set the background colour for both the textviews in the row.

How should I go about implementing the whole row selection?
Thanks

Comment: try changing background of linearlayout of the whole row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May these will work for you

```
     dataListView.setAdapter(aa);
    //attach a listener to the list view
    dataListView.setOnItemClickListener (listener);

    dataListView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
```

Use OnItem Click Listener and do your stuff in it.

```
OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener (){
 @Override
  onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
  ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId)).getText();
  //or do your stuff }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use/add this in to your ListView : 
**android:listSelector="@color/colorPrimary"**

**Example :**

```
 <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:listSelector="@color/colorPrimary">
</ListView>
```